# How can I do to add two more entries just changing one parameter?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

Hello I have these entries from the table informations :

```
|name| city| birthplace|client|
|peter| los angeles| new york|yes|
|william| chicago| denver|yes|
```

And I would like to do something like this :

```
|name| city| birthplace|client|
|peter| los angeles| new york|yes|
|william| chicago| denver|yes|
|peter| los angeles| new york|no|
|william| chicago| denver|no|
```

That is to say I would like to add the same lines but for the column client set no for the new lines. How can I do this using Django ?

Here is my first line of this :

```
info = informations.objects.filter(client='yes')
```

and that last line returns this 2 entries.

Thank you very much !

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Clone existed rows with "no" in last column?

Comment: Yes it is exactly what I want to do !

Comment: You can use a post_save signal for this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
infoObjects = informations.objects.filter(client='yes')
for info in infoObjects:
    newObj = info
    newObj.pk = None
    newObj.client = "no"
    newObj.save()
```